Is every element of this sequence of polynomials irreducible?
Remember how, when we first read Euclid's proof of the infinitude of the primes, we thought that his formula
$$
S = 1+\prod_{i=1}^n p_i 
$$
might actually be used to generate a new prime $S$ directly from the first $n$ primes $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$, and got rather disappointed when it turned out to be false. (Or maybe it was just me.)
I realized with a shock that I had never asked myself the same question for polynomials. What if we set $f_1 = X$, and then for $n>1$ we define
$$
f_{n+1} = 1 + \prod_{i=1}^n f_i.
$$
Are all $f_n$ irreducible?

Edit: Using an online Sage calculator, I have verified the irreducibility of the $f_n$ up to $f_{15}$, which has degree $2^{13}$.

You mean irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$, right? (or $\Bbb Z[x]$, they're all monic anyways...)

Yes, irreducible over the rational numbers.

It creates an irreducible if you suppose the number of irreducible is finite. This is juste used for contradiction. Otherwise this is clearly false in general for example take real polynomials. Also there is no "good" order on polynomials

This alternative form of the recursion $$f_n=\begin{cases}X&\text{if }n=1\ X+1&\text{if }n=2\ f_{n-1}^2-f_{n-1}+1&\text{if }n>2\end{cases}$$ might be easier to handle.

@SassatelliGiulio You are right, this is a very good idea. It seems to follow from your alternative definition that the zeros $\alpha_i$ of the $f_i$ define a chain of field extensions $\mathbb Q(\alpha_1) \subset \mathbb Q(\alpha_2) \subset \ldots$. From which it would also follow that if any $f_n$ is irreducible, then all $f_i$ with $i<n$ are likewise irreducible (since every step of the chain must be of degree either 1 or 2). Now from some hasty calculations I get the idea that $f_{2+2^k}(X) \equiv X^{2^{2^k}}+X+1 \pmod{2}$. So if we could prove that this is irreducible mod 2, we'd be done.

@R.P. using Mathematica, I found that $f_6(x)$, $f_{10}(x)$, and $f_{18}(x)$ are reducible mod $2$, and I believe this persists for larger $k$, so I think you need a different subsequence of polynomials.

@Pranay Thank you very much! I don't have easy access to a CAS right now, but I probably also should do some experiments before I proceed.

@R.P. The irreducibility of $f^2 - f + 1$ does not imply irreducibility of $f$ - e.g. take $f(x) = x^2$. I think you're confusing this recursion with something like $f_n(x) = f_{n-1}(x^2-x+1)$, for which your statement is true.

@BenjaminWright I agree that in general that does not hold, but in this case we have that $f_n$  equals $g \circ g \circ \ldots \circ g$ applied to $f_2=X+1$, where $g=X^2-X+1$ and there are $n-2$ applications of $g$. Therefore in fact $f_n(X-1)$ equals  $g \circ g \circ \ldots \circ g$, which puts us exactly in the situation you mention for which my statement holds (and of course the irreducibity of $f_n$ follows from that of $f_n(X-1)$)...

@R.P. Ah, yes, I missed that.

As suggested in the comments by Mr. Sassatelli, we may alternatively define the polynomials $f_n$ by $f_1=X$, $f_2=X+1$, and
$$
f_{n} = f_{n-1}^2 - f_{n-1} + 1
$$
for all $n \geq 3$.
Writing $g$ for the polynomial $X^2 - X + 1$, the above definitions unwinds to give $f_3 = g \circ f_2$, $f_4 = g \circ g \circ f_2$, etc.
We will show that $f_n=g \circ g \circ \cdots \circ g \circ f_2$ is irreducible. We will do this by actually showing that it is irreducible modulo 5. Also note that it suffices to show that $g \circ g \circ \cdots \circ g$ is irreducible, in effect undoing the translation $X \mapsto X+1$.
Now take an algebraic closure $k$ of $\mathbb{F}_5$, set $\alpha_1=0$, and iteratively define $\alpha_i \in k$ for $i\geq 2$ to be a zero of $g^{\circ (i-1)}$, the $(i-1)$-fold application of $g$, in such a way that, for $i > 2$ we have $g(\alpha_i)=\alpha_{i-1}$, which we may obviously do since $g$ maps the zeros of $g^{\circ (i-1)}$ unto those of $g^{\circ (i-2)}$. We then have the chain of inclusions $\mathbb F_5=\mathbb F_5(\alpha_1) \subset \mathbb F_5(\alpha_2) \subset \mathbb F_5(\alpha_3) \subset \ldots$. We will write $K_i = \mathbb F_5(\alpha_i)$.
Since $g=X^2-X+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_5$ (the discriminant $-3$ not being a square in that field), the field $\mathbb F_5(\alpha_2)$ is of degree $2$ over $\mathbb F_5$. We will aim to prove that $K_i$ is of degree $2$ over $K_{i-1}$ for all $i \geq 2$, thereby proving the irreducibility of $f_i$.
Let now $i>2$ be such that for all $2\leq j<i$ we have $[K_j : K_{j-1}]=2$. Since $g(\alpha_{i})=\alpha_{i-1}$, we get that $\alpha_i$ satisfies the polynomial
$$
X^2 - X + 1 - \alpha_{i-1},
$$
which has discriminant $\delta_{i-1}= 2 + 4 \alpha_{i-1}$. From this we conclude that $\alpha_i \in K_{i-1}$ if and only if $\delta_{i-1} = 2 + 4 \alpha_{i-1}$ is square in $K_{i-1}$. Therefore our aim is achieved when we prove that $\delta_{i-1}$ is not square in $K_{i-1}$.
An easy exercise in finite field theory shows that, for an odd prime power $q$, an element $x \in \mathbb F_{q^2}$ is square in $\mathbb F_{q^2}$ if and only if its norm $\operatorname{N}_{\mathbb F_{q^2}/\mathbb F_{q}}(x)$ is square in $\mathbb F_q$. (I won't do this exercise here since it would make the answer a bit too meandering, but it's easy.) Therefore, to decide whether or not $\delta_{i-1}$ is a square in $K_{i-1}$ we consider its norm $\delta_{i-2}'=(2+4\alpha_{i-1})(1-4\alpha_{i-1})=2-4 \alpha_i-16\alpha_i^2=2-4\alpha_{i-1}-16(\alpha_{i-1}+\alpha_{i-2}-1)=3+4 \alpha_{i-2}$, where we have used that the conjugate of $\alpha_{i-1}$ over $K_{i-2}$ equals $1-\alpha_{i-1}$. In sum, the element $\delta_{i-1}=2+4\alpha_{i-1}$ is square in $K_{i-1}$ if and only if the element $\delta_{i-2}'=3+4\alpha_{i-2}$ is square in $K_{i-2}$. (The reason for the "prime" in the notation for the norm of $\delta_{i-1}$ will become clear shortly.)
To wit, if we repeat this calculation, we will find that the element $\delta_{i-2}'=3+4\alpha_{i-2}$ is square in $K_{i-2}$ if and only if the element $\delta_{i-3}=2+4\alpha_{i-3}$ is square in $K_{i-3}$. So we see that if we show, as the base case of our induction, that the elements $\delta_2=2+4\alpha_2$ and $\delta_2'=3+4\alpha_2$ are not squares in $K_2$, then none of the elements $\delta_i$ and $\delta_i'$ are squares in $K_i$ for all $i>2$, and so all extensions $K_{i-1} \subset K_i$ are of degree $2$, which would prove the aimed-for proposition.
To do this, we take the norms of the elements $\delta_2$ and $\delta_2'$ once more, and find that they have norms $3$ and $2$ respectively in $\mathbb F_5$, which of course are not squares in that field. QED.
